# MySQL #1054 - Unknown column

Tags: mysql, joomla, mysql-error-1054

I want to execute this SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM  `wcf1_user` WHERE  `lastActivityTime` < 1343642175
```

But I receive this error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column '1343642175' in 'where clause'
```

But this makes absolutely no sense. 1343642175 isn't my column, lastActivityTime is it.

I tried it in phpMyAdmin like this:
[phpmyadmin](http://bildupload.sro.at/a/images/phpmyadmin.jpg)

[image]

The error is the same.

Any ideas?

Here is my full code:

```
$date = strtotime("-1 month");
$db = & JDatabase::getInstance( $option );
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query ->select('userID, username, email, lastActivityTime')
       ->from('wcf1_user')
       ->where('lastActivityTime < '.(int) $date);
$db->setQuery($query);
$result=$db->loadObjectList();
```

Note: that this is made inside a joomla component

EDIT:

Now it works fine, I haven't done anything to my code. I just restarted my Computer.
I don't know what caused this error, but now it's gone.

Comment: `lastActivityTime` is integer type ?

Comment: can you post your table structure and some sample data?

Comment: lastActivityTime is int(10)

Comment: Cool that it works now but you might Check your quoting. You want to make sure to enforce the right quoting so try:  
$query->where($db->quotename('lastActivityTime') . ' < '. (int) $date);


BTW a great trick is to echo $query->dump() to see the generated query.

Answer (score 0):

The number you are using isn't a number. It contains strange characters. 
Try to manually type the number.

Answer (score 0):

your query is wroking good , maybe you are giving not full code.

look [**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b13ab/1)

EDIT.

```
   $date=strtotime("-1 month");
   $db = & JDatabase::getInstance( $option );
   $query = $db->getQuery(true); 
   $query ->select('userID, username, email, lastActivityTime');
   $query->from('wcf1_user');
   $query->where('lastActivityTime < '.(int) $date); 
   $db->setQuery($query);
   $result=$db->loadObjectList();
```

Comment: here is my full code: [code]$date=strtotime("-1 month");$db = & JDatabase::getInstance( $option );
   
   $query = $db->getQuery(true);

   $query
                ->select('userID, username, email, lastActivityTime');
       ->from('wcf1_user');
       ->where('lastActivityTime < '.(int) $date);
            
   $db->setQuery($query);$result=$db->loadObjectList();[code]

Comment: in your code you are missing `$query` ;LOOK my updated answer

Comment: ohh sry. some comments had been in my code and i deleted them to make my code clear for this thread. i must have deleted the $query while deleting the comments

Comment: but my code cant be wrong. i typed it in inside phpmyadmin and it didnt worked, too.

Comment: try remove space between `(int) $date`  to `(int)$date`

Comment: no change, but when the error is in my code, why doesnt it work when i type the query directly into phpmyadmin?

Comment: your date is already integer so try this `where('lastActivityTime < '.$date);`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:

```
$date = strtotime("-1 month");
$db = JDatabase::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query ->select('userID, username, email, lastActivityTime')
       ->from('#__user')
       ->where('lastActivityTime < '.(int) $date);
$db->setQuery($query);
$result=$db->loadObjectList();
```

With Joomla, the table has a global prefix which is `#__`

Hope this helps

Comment: i dont acces a joomla-db. in $option, there is the data for the other db and this works fine in other places.

Comment: are you putting this query in a Joomla file or external file? If external, are you importing the the Joomla database library?

Comment: im using this inside a joomla component, that is used by joomla.